# command-t plugin in MacVim - makes MacVim not work

Tags: ruby, vim, rvm, macvim

I'm trying to use the [command-t fuzzy finder plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) for MacVim.

I followed the directions but my MacVim no longer works; No window shows, but it still looks like it starts up since the app icon is on the dock. If I remove the command-t folder in `~/.vim/ruby`, my MacVim works as normal. I'm thinking it's an incompatibility with Ruby versions? The one MacVim uses versus the RVM one I use to compile command-t.  Has anyone else had this problem?

I'm using RVM with ruby 1.9.2, but when I do `:Ruby p RUBY_VERSION`, it says 1.8.7. When I try compiling MacVim from source with the ruby-interp setting, the end result is the same.

EDIT: I've also tried to just use rvm use system before `ruby extconf.rb` and `make` of the command-t plugin, which uses ruby version 1.8.7, the same as `:ruby p RUBY_VERSION` in macvim, but it still does not work. So I really don't know what the problem is--the versions match. The output of the make is not ideal:
`make cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o ext.bundle ext.o match.o matcher.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -lruby -lpthread -ldl ld: warning: in ext.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) ld: warning: in match.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386) ld: warning: in matcher.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started using [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) and it solved all of these kinds of issues for me.  Plus, it adds all kinds of other cool vim magic.  Highly recommended.

Comment: I now just use Janus as well, the Cmd T it comes with is great.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Do what you said you did in your edit, but before that, run `make clean`. Everything works fine now for me :)

Comment: Used `rvm use system` then `ruby extconf.rb` then `make clean` then `make` and this worked.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are actually using the system ruby: with `homebrew` I had both rvm and ruby installed, so `rvm use system` would make me use `/usr/local/bin/ruby` instead of `/usr/bin/ruby`. Uninstalled ruby with homebrew, recompiled and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-and-Ruby-RVM-td3325517.html#a3334151) help you at all? Pay attention to the post right after it for a correction.

Comment: That's where I got the idea to do a build from source with the rubyinterp configuration.  I tried the patch recently, and while it allows macvim to run, when I do :CommandT, it says it needs a vim compiled with ruby support (which I did...) :(

Answer (score 0):

thats true, I had rvm pointing to 1.9.2 and then I installed 1.8.7, there was this issue all the time, until i used the janus and it worked.